# How should I handle community promotion ad images in HTTPS edits?

Tags: discussion, ssl, community-promotion-ads

I came across the [following post](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1575/29269) via the [Crowdcrafting image cleanup project](https://crowdcrafting.org/project/sehttpimagescleanup/newtask):

[image]

It's one of the community promotion ad posts. I am not sure what to do.

The image link is broken (both http and https area51 links do not load this image). I could look for it in a cache somewhere and upload it, but the thing is I kind of don't know how the community promotion ads work. Isn't there some kind of... automation there or something? They've always been a mystery to me.

Does something rely on the answers being of a certain format with very specific links, or can I just treat this as normal? The "All answers should be in the exact form of..." in the promotion ad descriptions is making me uncertain. What action should be taken here?

The post doesn't exactly have much value, it could probably just be deleted altogether, but still, if I run into community promotion ads in the future, can I just change out the image links or will it break something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The posts themselves are obsolete in this case - If the post makes no sense without the images, there's no images to be found, and there's no discernible loss to the community from deletion, deletion is the right option.

I believe the exact format is just a bit of pre-emptive housekeeping rather than any hard and fast rule. Even if there was some script picking ads, its doubtful it would need to run on 3-4 year old posts.